# Sci-fi cartoon from 70s or 80s about androids and giant heart

Tags: story-identification, androids

It must have been late 80s when I watched that cartoon on old VHS. I don’t remember details well but there were white androids in the story, kept prisoners by other robots that were controlled by a giant heart. At the end they managed to destroy the heart by stubbing it. Any idea?

Comment: They stubbed a heart?

Comment: How does one stub a heart?

Comment: I assume stabbing...

Comment: It might have been a burning heart, that they stubbed out.

Comment: Despite the joke, it sounds a bit like part of one episode of Josie and the Pussy Cats In Outer Space, I'll see if I can track it down.